# Could not load the following font issue in iReport

Tags: windows-vista, jasper-reports, ireport

We have our own fonts for our application. We are using `Windows Vista` operating system to develop the reports using `iReport`. We are using `iReports 3.7.1`.

I kept all my fonts in a folder in C:\ drive. I gave fonts path in `iReport`.
Still I am getting 'Could not load the font' error while generating the report.

The same worked fine on `Windows 2000` and with `iReport 2.x versions`.

Comment: This deosn't appear to be a crystal reports issue - can the crystal-reports tag be removed?

Comment: Agreed. Can the original poster please remove the crystal-reports tag?

Comment: It was added by someone.. I don't know why they added. I got issue with the Ireport and Windows Vista only.

Answer (score 0):

This is, er, not exactly a timely reply. But you should use font extensions. They were added to handle this type of problem.

Putting your font files into the classpath also works in many cases (as you indicated). But it fails for some unanticipated reasons as well (as you indicated!). Font Extensions will avoid these problems.